# How do I press power key on a bluetooth keyboard?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, keyboard, bluetooth

1. How do I lock my Android device using the bluetooth keyboard?
2. How do I call up "Reboot, Airplane mode, etc." menu from keyboard?
3. Can I issue a forced poweroff from bluetooth keyboard, like when holding the power key?

Answer (score 0):

Is your Android rooted? Has it got a button designed for that purpose? If your Android **is rooted** then you would have to manually install a app (Search google for something like 'Bluetooth Android Keyboard Power Options') and if your device is **not rooted** then it is nearly impossible to give a `Shut Down` command from even a app, though I could be wrong